# Fastest way to generate random bits for Brownian Motion simulation with Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

**TL;DR: I try to generate large amounts of random numbers from a set of `[-1, 1]` I found out that `np.random.Generator.choice` is the worst method while the best one is to use `np.random.Generator.random` and move from boolean and to integer. Is there a better way to generate such random numbers in large amounts?**

I want to simulate the motion of `m` particles in a closed container with reflective surfaces in d-D in a mesh for `n` iterations. There is also a hitting condition that I check after every iteration. Without loss of generality, let's assume `d=2`.

Since I use a mesh, the movement part boils down to generating -1s and +1s. At this point, I treat each particle individually in a loop so after generating these -1s and  +1s, I access them in a loop and as the number of particles still in the system decreases, I generate less numbers. This part can be improved and I am open to comments but it is not what I am asking.

My question is **what the fastest way is to generate many random numbers from the set `[-1,1]`.** I thought of five approaches, four with np and with random.

I firstly thought that the obvious choice was `np.random.Generator.choice([-1,1],size=(m,2))`. It took 595.6 seconds.

```py
n=int(5e6)
m=1000
rng=np.random.default_rng()
tic=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    a=rng.choice([-1,1], size=(m,2))
    for j in range(m): #This useless loop is here to demonstrate that I am accessing each line one by one
        b=a[j]
print("choice",time.time()-tic)
```

I tried to move from uniform~[0,1) to integers -1 and +1 with code below, which took 527.6 s. Note that the +0 part converts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`.

```py
n=int(5e6)
m=1000
rng=np.random.default_rng()
tic=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    a=(rng.random(size=(m,2))>0.5+0)*2-1
    for j in range(m): 
        b=a[j]
print("operate",time.time()-tic)
```

I tried something very similar with `np.sign`, which took 543.5 s.

```py
n=int(5e6)
m=1000
rng=np.random.default_rng()
tic=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    a=np.sign(rng.random(size=(m,2))-0.5)
    for j in range(m):
        b=a[j]
print("sign",time.time()-tic)
```

Finally, I tried `np.random.Generator.integers` with a few extra manipulations. It took 553.8 s.

```py
n=int(5e6)
m=1000
rng=np.random.default_rng()
tic=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    a=(rng.integers(2,size=(m,2))*2)-1
    for j in range(m):
        b=a[j]
print("integer",time.time()-tic
```

Since I access them one by one, I could also use the `random.random()` on the spot. It takes far too long (~750 s).

What baffles me most is that `rng.choice()` is by far the worst choice. I knew that it didn't work well for small set size, but since `m` is large, I thought it can redeem itself. I am also surprised that boolean to integer transition offers the fastest solution.

So, my question is, what is the fastest way to generate `m*d` random integers belonging to the set `[-1,1]`? Is it one of those that I tried or am I missing something? Or am I not even on the right track?

Comment: @pjs I can't say I timed them under zero gravity. The computer was always connected to the charger and I didn't use any CPU-hogging program. (Just chrome to prepare a draft for this question.) Regarding consistency, I first tried it with ```int(1e6)``` iterations. "Operate" took 109.1 s, "sign" took 112.9 s, "integer" took 114.8 s and "choice" took 123,6 s. I would say the timings were very consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a lot faster to generate 32 bit unsigned integers, and extract 32 random bits from each integer.  By asking for a full range, I believe that avoids any scaling or conversion overhead from manipulating the words pulled from the `rng`, so it should be the most efficient (eg, calling `rng.bytes` uses this method, see [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e5c39c8a89c4a7165136773e06d0042240be49fa/numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L597)):

```py
import numpy as np

m = 65536
rng = np.random.default_rng()
max_int = 2 ** 32

def choice():
    return rng.choice([-1,1], size=(m,2))

def random():
    return (rng.random(size=(m,2))>0.5+0)*2-1

def uint32_32x_too_many():
    return rng.integers(0, max_int, size=(m, 2), dtype=np.uint32)

def uint32():
    return rng.integers(0, max_int, size=(m//32, 2), dtype=np.uint32)
```

Benchmarking gives (the file name is `rand.py`):

```
python -mtimeit -s'import rand' 'rand.choice()'
500 loops, best of 5: 537 usec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'import rand' 'rand.random()'
500 loops, best of 5: 650 usec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'import rand' 'rand.uint32_32x_too_many()'
1000 loops, best of 5: 260 usec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'import rand' 'rand.uint32()'
20000 loops, best of 5: 11.9 usec per loop
```

Notice that `uint32_32x_too_many()` generates `m*2` 32-bit random ints (ie, 32x more random bits than required), and is considerably faster than `choice` or `random`. But `uint32()` is dramatically faster - it only generates `m//32 * 2` random ints, but that is still the required `m * 2` random bits.

Accessing the random bits in the packed integers will be slightly more expensive.  To test the k-th bit, you access bit number `k % 32` at index `k // 32`, eg:

```py
(a[k // 32] >> (k % 32)) & 1
```

If that proves to be slower than you would like, one optimization is to have an inner loop sized so that it consumes 32 random bits.  Then you can simply use one new random int per loop, and inside the loop you can test for each random bit, and shift the int each time:

```py
rand_bit = rand_int & 1
rand_int = rand_int >> 1
```

If your inner loop is not scalar and requires an array of random bits, then you can efficiently vectorize the conversion of random 32-bit integers to an array of random bits with, eg:

```py
num_ints = 10
a = rng.integers(0, 2**32, size=(num_ints))
rand_bits = (np.repeat(a, 32) >>  np.tile(np.arange(0, 32), num_ints)) & 1
```

This sets `rand_bits` to an array of 320 random 0/1 values.

Comment: I think I found a better way but inspired by your method. ```a=rng.integers(0, max_int, size=(m//4), dtype=np.uint8)``` and then ```a=np.unpackbits(a).reshape(m,2)*2-1```. This is superior to the "operate" routine I described above by 9.4%. Unfortunately unpackbits only works for uint8, this is why I changed your uint32 and fixed the max_int accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to speedup things (not only RNG) is to use [numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

```
import numpy as np
import time
from numba import njit, prange

n=int(5e6)
m=1000
rng=np.random.default_rng()
tic=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    a=(rng.random(size=(m,2))>0.5+0)*2-1
print("operate",time.time()-tic)

@njit(parallel=True)
def getRandomNumbers(n):
    a = np.zeros(n)
    for i in prange(n):
        a[i] = (np.random.rand()>0.5+0)*2-1
    return a

tic=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    a = getRandomNumbers(2*m).reshape((m,2))
print("numba",time.time()-tic)
```

The output:

```
operate 68.01399993896484
numba 43.64120006561279
```

You can also try to use [numba's GPU accelerated RNG](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/random.html). Could be the fastest, especially for large scale problems. Disclaimer: never tried it myself.

P.S. Simple single-threaded approach in C++ takes ~10 seconds. Parallel variant will be times faster. Consider using a C++ backend library to produce the numbers.

Comment: I was more looking for an RNG-oriented answer but still thank you! But I have to ask, how did you manage to do "operate" eight times faster than I did? I have a R9 5900HX cpu. I know notebooks do not perform as good as desktops, but the difference shouldn't account for such a huge difference.

Comment: The "useless loop" has been omitted, because there is no point to benchmark it. Non-vectorized explicit loop **is** slow, and memory operations (allocation, deallocation, read, write) are slow too. Your code without alterations takes 780 s. For example, C++ routine that stores the result is memory, takes 10 s. The non-storing takes 6.6 s.

Comment: I see. You are right that the useless loop is actually useless. I needed the useless loop to distinguish between using ```random.random()``` after each iteration and using np random for bulk generation of random variables, but after eliminating random random, there was no need for it.